# php call java web service get internal server error 500

Tags: java, php, web-services

i had a java web service and a php client in local host..
i use php to call java web service buy this come out internal server error 500.
any wrong from the code

```
private function getWebService() {
    $ws = 'http://localhost:8080/Pineaaplews/services/PineappleHellow?wsdl';
     $options = array('features' => SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE + SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);
    $client = new SoapClient($ws,$options);
    $response = $client->addMethod(2,3);
    $this->response = array('testStr' => $response);
}
```

Comment: Can you check your server error log for more detail error message?

Comment: Is the URL http://localhost:8080/Pineaaplews/services accessible from where you are running php client?
any java server logs you can mention here will be helpful.

Comment: all web from local.